# Combining Production Rules using Reinforcement Learning

Tags: reference-request, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning

Production systems have been used to solve puzzles such as the Tower of Hanoi for years with hard-coded production rules. However, has there been any research in using reinforcement learning to combine basic production rules into more complex ones with the goal of solving a puzzle?

Note that I've asked [a similar question on Cogsci.SE](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/11046/reinforcement-learning-for-combining-production-rules), but with a greater cognitive perspective. In my opinion, the two perspectives are different enough to merit semi-cross-posting.

Answer (score 1):

this writeup by Kenan Deen solves the [Tower of Hanoi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi) problem with reinforcement learning and Markoff decision processes.

- [Tower of Hanoi – Reinforcement Learning](https://kenandeen.wordpress.com/2015/08/22/tower-of-hanoi-reinforcement-learning/)

there is some other research on using [genetic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_programming) in "solving" (successfully playing) video games. these approaches do find "subroutines" that can be regarded as subgoals. for example, in playing pacman, an algorithm might have a subroutine/ subgoal that eats ghosts if they are blue, otherwise, run away from them. the sample algorithms are sometimes encoded as LISP-like trees. see eg

- [Evolving diverse Ms. Pac-Man playing agents using genetic programming](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/224191003_Evolving_diverse_Ms._Pac-Man_playing_agents_using_genetic_programming) / Lucas.
- possibly the earliest case of this technique for solving pacman was reported by Koza in 1992 in the book [Genetic Programming: on the programming of computers by means of natural selection](https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/genetic-programming)